# Как правильно написать: "Жду вас на занятиИ" или "Жду вас на занятиЕ"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать: "Жду вас на занятиИ" или "Жду вас на занятиЕ"?

Answer (score 3):

***Жду вас (где?) на занятии***.- Значение обстоятельства места. Вы  находитесь на занятии и ждёте.

***Жду вас (куда? с какой целью?) на занятие***. - Значение обстоятельства места и ***цели***.  Вы можете ждать людей где угодно, они придут, и вы вместе пойдёте на занятие. Ср.: *Ждем вас на отдых в Сочи.* (Газета "Краснодарские известия"); *А в Новокузнецке к визиту президента подготовились еще в декабре прошлого года, тогда его ждали на открытие турнира по дзюдо.* (Примеры из Нацкорпуса)

Добавлю, что в русском языке выражения  типа ***жду на обед, на ужин, на тренировку, на занятие*** всё более активно употребляются, а, например,  общепринятое *жду к обеду, к ужину* постепенно сдаёт позиции.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **жду вас на занятии (П.п.)**

**Ждать (где?) — это обычный вопрос.** Можно ждать на улице, на вокзале, на остановке и т.д. (обстоятельство места). Можно ждать на морозе или на жаре (при каких условиях). Также можно ждать на второй день (обстоятельство времени).

Но мне **не встречалось** такое выражение: *ждать (куда?) на занятие, на тренировку.* В Нацкорпусе такое сочетание также не обнаружилось, нет таких примеров в словарях.

Возможно, это какой-то просторечный вариант, но я сомневаюсь, что такая грамматика на сегодняшний день является нормированной.

**Дополнение**

Смысл в этой фразе, как мне кажется, прочитывается такой: Я жду, что вы придете на **мое** занятие (так может сказать **педагог**, который проводит занятие). Затем предложение упрощается, и получается "жду вас на занятие". Но этот вариант пока **не может считаться литературной нормой**, хотя такие записи можно встретить в Сети.

Comment: Понятно. спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я кратко, там можно и дальше раскладывать, но воздержусь. 
**Жду вас на занятии** - то есть я буду там и жду вас там. Простая выдача сведений о месте нахождения говорит о просьбе. То есть в этом случае звучит просьба. 
**Жду вас на занятие** - а здесь как указание. Может быть и вежливое обращение, но закладывается обязывание и даже вменение. 
Добавлю, если "жду на занятиИ" говорит о том, что ждущий будет присутствовать на занятии, то "жду на занятиЕ" - совсем не обязательно, что ждущий будет присутствовать на занятии (он все равно потом узнает о тех, кто присутствовал, а кто пропустил, это "жду" в данном случае указывает на контроль). По-моему, этот момент (отсутствия, может не тренер, а менеджер это произносит) убедительно доказывает правильность высказывания "жду на занятиЕ".

Comment: Скажите, на основании чего Вы делаете вывод о правильности грамматической формы жду (куда?) на занятие. Это только Ваше личное мнение или Вы встречали этот вариант в письменном виде и можете подтвердить ссылкой на литературу по этой теме. Выбор правильного падежа - это грамматика, существуют словари сочетаемости слов, справочники по управлению. А что если Вы предлагаете  просторечную форму, нигде не зафиксированную. Ведь автор вопроса ждет, что мы не только определим правильность (нормативность) сочетания, но и укажем источник, подтверждающий это.

Comment: В данном случае о правильности говорить не стоит. Здесь вопрос в сути выражений, то есть какую мысль хочет человек выразить. В "жду на занятиЕ" имеется строгость, установка. Может это и надо иногда проявлять преподавателю, чтобы внушить ответственность ученикам.

Comment: Я думаю, что о правильности нужно всегда говорить в первую очередь. Здесь люди задают не праздные, а практические вопросы. Автору нужно составить текст и выбрать правильное сочетание, в котором нет грамматических и стилистических ошибок. Я согласна, что смысловые оттенки могут быть разными, но пока в языке есть только одна нормативная форму, которую и следует применить. Или Вы можете доказать нормативность другой формы?

Comment: В первую очередь нужно говорить о точности, четкости. И они же устанавливают правильность. Вы раскладываете выражения: "жду куда?" и "жду где?". Я раскладываю: "жду кого?, жду на что?" и "жду кого? жду на чём?". А раз всплывают падежи, то и расклад должен быть по падежам (с каждого выражения по шесть частей можно разложить, но это сложно).

Comment: Жду на занятиях https://www.proza.ru/2013/03/19/2092

Comment: Точность и четкость - это ваше личное видение проблемы, а правильность - это объективная характеристика, соответствие норме. Я ничего не раскладываю, а просто вижу, что глагол ждать с предлогом НА управляют П. падежом, но не В. падежом. Зайдите в Нацкорпус по ссылке, и вы увидите только П.п. (всего 140 примеров). Вы можете найти В.п.? http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E6%E4%E0%F2%FC+%ED%E0 Жду на занятиях  (где?) - это П.п.

Comment: Вторая же ссылка "жду вас на ужин"... http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E6%E4%F3+%E2%E0%F1+%ED%E0

Comment: Что ж, неплохо. А кроме ужина, обеда и завтрака, есть что-нибудь еще? Думается мне, что управление В.п. подходит не ко всем существительным. Сочетаемость у слов бывает индивидуальная.

Comment: я погуглил, там еще больше этих "жду вас на занятиях", в ютубе особенно.

Comment: Жду на занятии, на занятиях - это П.п.

Comment: Исправляюсь: "Жду на занятиЕ" https://www.google.ru/search?lr=lang_ru&newwindow=1&hl=ru&as_qdr=all&tbs=lr%3Alang_1ru&ei=b7-IXIf0DY_SrgT1777YAg&q=%22%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%22&oq=%22%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39.3233.7125..7754...0.0..0.248.304.1j0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.NSnz-s13T_U

Comment: Замечательно поработали. А теперь определите стиль этих выражений. Разговорный ненормированный, я так думаю. Я еще в ответе предполагала, что это упрощенная грамматика: жду, что вы придете на занятие, жду на занятие.  Кстати, выражение "жду Вас на ужин" построено по той же схеме, но получило распространение в речи. Но есть в нем некая двусмысленность: жду на ужин Вас -  и запеченную курицу, например.

Comment: Я противник "разговорное, ненормативное, устаревшее" - это отговорки по незнанию. Наверное, мне так и придётся разложить оба выражения по полочкам 6 частей по "на занятиИ" и 6 частей по "на занятиЕ". Эти деления всё расставят по местам.

Comment: Вы противник, но не автор вопроса, а Вы отвечаете именно ему.  И стилевые пометки - это не отговорки авторов словарей по незнанию (я думаю. что  надо более уважительно относиться к их труду). Словарь - это тот же закон, а цивилизованные люди должны соблюдать законы и правила. Так что раскладывайте по полочкам и приводите ссылки на источники. Кстати, записи в Сети учитываются, но высоко не ценятся. Сами понимаете, что литературные нормы там необязательны, а на грамотность участников не жалуется только ленивый. Удачи Вам, спасибо за беседу.

Comment: Благодарю всех! (не ожидала такой дискуссии). Делаю вывод, что литературной нормой будет "Жду на занятии". Еще раз всем огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если это индивидуальный тренер или репетитор, и он "ждёт **на занятии**" (*на каком мероприятии?*), это означает, что занятие началось или начнётся без учеников. Если же другие ученики есть, то "на занятии" ждать можно только опоздавшего. "Где" происходит ожидание - вопрос отдельный.

Ждать (прихода) кого-либо **на занятие** можно, подобно тому, как человека "ждут на новоселье (день рождения)" (**на какое мероприятие?**) или "в гости" (в каком качестве?). Пример, когда вариант *"на занятии"* не подходит: *Он ждал своего единственного ученика на занятие, но не дождался.*

Comment: Alex_ander, у нас есть индивидуальная СОЧЕТАЕМОСТЬ слов? Допустим, что глагол ждать сочетается  с  некоторыми сущ. в В.п. (жду на новоселье, на обед, на юбилей и т.д.). Но это не значит, что он также свободно сочетается с любыми существительными. И если такой сочетаемости пока нет, то  не надо использовать подобные предложения, нужно заменять их другими. Вы где-нибудь видели в нормальной литературе или в учебниках сочетание глагола  "ждать" с этими словами: жду на урок, на занятие, на тренировку, на репетицию?

Comment: У меня есть  "Словарь грамматической сочетаемости слов" РАН, 2013 год. Там есть статья про глагол "ждать", в основном рассматривается выбор "жду поезд - жду поезда", но примеров приводится много, причем часто используются придаточные предложения (жду, что...). Но нет ничего похожего на "жду на занятие".