# Может ли глагол "ждать" управлять винительным падежом с предлогом НА?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

***Жду вас на праздник, жду вас на ужин*** — обычные фразы, которые кажутся нам вполне корректными. Но почему тогда возникают сомнения в правильности похожих сочетаний: ***жду на занятие, на урок, на репетицию***?

Но, может быть, глагол ***ждать*** вовсе и не управляет существительными в форме винительного падежа  с предлогом НА, то есть сочетания ***на праздник, на ужин*** — это детерминанты.

***Детерминантами*** называются неприсловные распространители, которые **относятся ко всему предложению** (к его грамматической основе), а не к конкретному слову. Иначе говоря, внутри предложения могут быть связи, не соотнесенные со словосочетаниями.

Хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение по этому вопросу.

Примечание

Обсуждение темы в вопросе [Как правильно написать: "Жду вас на занятиИ" или "Жду вас на занятиЕ"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449404/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%96%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%98-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%96%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%95/449417?noredirect=1#comment460169_449417)

Comment: у меня не возникают таких сомнений. а у кого они возникают?

Comment: что плохого в том чтобы "управлять существительными в форме винительного падежа с предлогом НА"?

Comment: Сомнение возникли у автора вопроса (см. ссылку). А вот что плохого в В.п.? Здесь речь идет не о хорошем или плохом, а о правильном. Как известно, падежное управление в русском языке регламентируется грамматическими правилами, поэтому выбор падежа существительного, которым управляет глагол ждать является нормированным, как и для любого другого слова. Существуют справочники по управлению, а также справочники    сочетаемости  конкретных слов. Вот и возникают сомнения: жду на занятии или на занятие? Как правильно? Оба ли варианта допустимые и нормированные или один из них разговорно-просторечный?

Answer (score 1):

Обязательным в таких конструкциях является обозначенный *предмет ожидания*, напр. в виде местоимения. Если его опускают в разговоре и тем более на письме ("жду на то-то"), результат воспринимается как просторечие (независимо от привычности или частотности сочетаний). Управление существительным после "на" (на какой предмет, на какое мероприятие, процедуру) осуществляется *не отдельно взятым глаголом* "ждать", а цельным высказыванием "жду кого (что)".

> Жду **вас** завтра *на укол* (на исповедь, на занятие, на мастер-класс по
>   выпечке).

На что человек *придёт* ("приход" всегда подразумевается), на то его и ждут.

О неодушевлённом предмете ожидания можно напр. сказать своей экономке, посланной на базар:

> Жду **рыбью голову** *на уху*.

На что рыбья голова *пойдёт*, на то её (принесения) и ждут. Отсюда видно, что глагол "ждать" управляет проблемным существительным *косвенно*, через законченное высказывание.

Comment: Alex_ander, понятие детерминанта не очень широко нам известно, его мало изучают. Смысл его в том, чтобы  не делить предложение на исходные словосочетания, отыскивая различные связи (управления и др.).  Например: Сестра налила  мне чаю.  Здесь управление "налила чаю", но не "налила мне". Словосочетания "налить мне" не существует, в предложении "мне" относится не к глаголу, а к предикативной основе "сестра налила". Аналогично: Жду вас завтра на укол. Здесь управление: жду вас, а завтра и на укол - это детерминанты,  они относятся не глаголу. а к сказуемому в односоставном предложении.

Comment: Управление от _глагола_ (он переходный) здесь всегда направлено на прямое дополнение, поэтому поиск другой его "жертвы" и приводит к странным ощущениям.

Comment: Детерминанты являются распространителями предикативной основы, их  присутствие в предложении определяют смысловую законченность высказывания, но здесь нет связи с падежным управлением.

Comment: Я рассматриваю управление "жду вас", это прямое дополнение. Жду вас, жду весны. Прийти на занятие - это правильное предложное управление. На занятии - обстоятельственный детерминант, обстоятельство места. Другое дело, как выбрать падеж для детерминанта. "На праздник, к празднику" - возможно, здесь обстоятельства времени,  а не места.   А "на занятие "- здесь такого обстоятельственного значения нет.